# Can static IP communicate with floating IP using ROS?

Tags: ip, communication, ros, 4g, dongle

I'm new to ROS, wish someone can answer my stupid question.

I have a static IP **140.113.xxx.xxx**, and a 4G dongle with floating IP **192.168.8.100**. **I want to use ROS to transmit data between them**. Can ROS do that? Because I found some website said ROS can only transmit data in the same Internet domain, but I think this must have some trick to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with ROS.Theses are IPs in two different networks, you either create a propper routing or you give a second device an IP in the same net. However 192.168.x.x should not be used in the internet or any other non private networks